# When I am creating a trigger for finding the grade of Student based on its AVG (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

```
CREATE TRIGGER grade123 ON student
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE student 
    SET grade = CASE
                   WHEN avg > 75 THEN 'firstclass'
                   WHEN avg > 50 AND avg < 75 THEN 'second class'
                   WHEN avg > 35 AND avg < 60 THEN 'third class'
                   ELSE 'fail'
                END
```

I get an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure grade123, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near 'END'

Kindly help me out

Comment: is AVG is a variable or you are looking for average of values?

Comment: No AVG is variable  ,and i store few values..then based on avg i need to find grade

Comment: just use avg with [] like [AVG]

Comment: You don't need a trigger to get the grade, just add a calculated column to the table or create a view

Comment: I get that you have some kind of school exam now, but please try to format your question properly next time before you post it

Comment: what man ...i know that process .. i want to update by using trigger

Comment: Bartosz X first u need to learn how to ans a question then add a comment

Comment: A trigger should *typically* somehow make use of the `Inserted` pseudo table to find those rows that were actually freshly inserted - you're just updating **each and EVERY row** in the whole table, each time a row is inserted....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a BEGIN for your trigger, you need to add another END.  Also the word AVG is a reserved word so you need to escape it.

```
CREATE TRIGGER grade123 ON student
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE student SET grade =
    CASE
        WHEN [avg] > 75 THEN 'first class'
        WHEN [avg] > 50 AND [avg] <= 75 THEN 'second class'
        WHEN [avg] > 35 AND [avg] < 60 THEN 'third class'
        ELSE 'fail'
    END
END
```

However as @marc_s said your trigger is currently updating EVERY row of the table EVERY time any row is inserted. So you should add a lookup to `inserted` which is a special table available to triggers that shows which records were modified

Assuming students looks like

```
CREATE TABLE students
(
    student_id int identity(1,1),
    grade varchar(10),
    [avg] int
)
GO
```

then

```
CREATE TRIGGER grade123 ON students
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE students SET grade =
    CASE
        WHEN [avg] > 75 THEN 'first class'
        WHEN [avg] > 50 AND [avg] <= 75 THEN 'second class'
        WHEN [avg] > 35 AND [avg] < 60 THEN 'third class'
        ELSE 'fail'
    END
    where student_id in (select student_id from inserted)
END
```

for the loop with an IF..ELSE (although I would NEVER use this in production but just for showing what it would look like)

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

declare @students table
(
    ident int identity(1,1),
    student_id int,
    [avg] int
)

INSERT INTO @students (student_id, [avg])
select student_id, [avg]
from students

declare @table_count int = (select COALESCE(count(ident),0) from @students)
declare @counter int = 1

declare @avg int

WHILE (@table_count > 0 AND @counter <= @table_count)
BEGIN
    select @avg = [avg]
    from @students
    where ident = @counter

    IF (@avg > 75)
        UPDATE students SET 
            grade = 'first class'
        WHERE student_id = @counter
    ELSE IF (@avg > 50 AND @avg <= 75)
        UPDATE students SET 
            grade = 'second class'
        WHERE student_id = @counter
    ELSE IF (@avg > 35 AND @avg < 60)
        UPDATE students SET 
            grade = 'third class'
        WHERE student_id = @counter
    ELSE
        UPDATE students SET 
            grade = 'fail'
        WHERE student_id = @counter

    set @counter += 1;
END
```

Comment: Can u Ans the Code for same in IF ELSE LOOP

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: Can u Write the same  Funcanality for geting the grade by Using Loop condition (IF)

Comment: You mean a loop with an IF statement instead of a case statement?  yes it's possible to do but much more work and not efficient

Comment: can u please ans that ..i need urgently